# Git bundle create by branch and tag including all objects without any update

Tags: git, bundle

I have a git project containing multiple branches

I want to keep updating an offline copy of this repository using git bundle based on tag. 
I generate bundle and then tag it.

I want to sync some branches only to keep my bundle size down.

Bundle is generated: git bundle create branch-list ^last_tag

The tag is done using: git tag -f branch-list tag_name

The branch-list for tagging and bundle create is same.

However just after generating a bundle and tagging, if I generate another bundle with this new tag it is compressing all objects and the bundle size is very large almost as much as the size of the git, when in fact it should be refusing to create empty bundle.

This behaviour is seen only in some gits. In some others it works fine. What is missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: A tag points to a single commit, which is likely on a single branch (although not necessarily if branches were created after the tag point). To accomplish what you want, I think you'll need to put a tag on each branch (and of course update your `git bundle create` command accordingly, including the branches and excluding all the tags).

Comment: @twalberg: Yes that is what I am doing. git tag -f branch-list tag_name   In this command branch-list is the list of all branches I wanted to tag with the tag name. Then in the git bundle create command I am specifying the same branch list with the tag name from where I want to create the bundle.

Comment: My problem is in some cases randomly, if I tag two branches and then create a bundle from this tag, the tag in one of the branches still points to the last commit made sometime before for that branch (2 months back) and the tag in other branch points to the latest commit. Now during bundle creation it is taking the old tag commit from 1st branch and generating a bundle with all the intermediate commits when in fact the bundle should be empty (there was no commit after the latest tag).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough - you can't tag more than one branch with one tag/name. A tag points to one specific commit. If that commit happens to exist in the history of two or more branches (because the branches diverged after that commit), then both commits *contain* that tag. But you can't tag multiple branches (i.e. branch heads - which are also simple pointers; really `git` doesn't have branches in the same way CVS/SVN does - a branch is a pointer to the last commit on one branch of tree, and thus *contains* the ancestors of that specific commit, which may belong to many branches).

Comment: Ah yes I understand. I am  giving only one (current dev branch) as the argument in git tag command and while creating bundle I give the list of branches I wanted to generate the bundle for. I think the behavior is that bundle will be created for all the commits after the the commit in tag for the branches in arg list

Comment: Actually, I was misunderstanding my problem. What is happening is that the tag is not being done even when I am specifying one branch for the git repository. I am doing a daily commit using cron but I just checked and there was no tag after after 23rd Jan. I ran the command manually but still there was no tag with todays date. I need to debug why this is happening. Thanks for your help!